# Shared text document where users can type in realtime Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, user-interaction

My goal is to create a text view where two users can type at the same time in a text document (for example UITextView). I am currently using firebase as my database.

One way one could implement this is to update a document all the time from firebase with listeners attached to it that update the text. This approach isn't very practical and can cause confusion right away when one internet connection is poor.

Is it possible to create a shared text document in Swift where two users can type? And is there a more convenient approach to it than mine?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for SO. Asking if something *is possible* is broad. Sure, it's possible but that's not really an answer. The other issue is we don't know the entire use case, for example *two users can type* - sure, that's easy. But what are the requirements? User A types Hello and user B types Goodbye - who wins? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the future, post CODE related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is essentially what [Firepad](https://firepad.io/) does on the web.

You could consider using its [source code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad) as the basis for your solution, paying special attention to the [operation transform](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad#repo-structure) implementation in there, which is what makes its multi-user editing of a single document possible.